# Ordenando uma segunda lista de acordo com a ordenação da primeira lista

Tags: python, lista

Tenho o seguinte (exemplo bobo):

```
lista=[[3,6,4,2,7],[8,4,6,4,3]]
```

Quero colocar `lista[0]` em ordem crescente, modificando `lista[1]` de acordo com `lista[0]`. Pra ilustrar o que quero segue abaixo:

```
lista_ordenada=[[2,3,4,6,7],[4,8,6,4,3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi, é isto que você quer:

```
primeira_lista = lista[0]
segunda_lista = lista[1]
tuplas = [(indice, valor) for indice, valor in enumerate(primeira_lista)]
# print(tuplas)
tuplas.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
# print(tuplas)
resultado = []
for indice, valor in tuplas:
    resultado.append(segunda_lista[indice])
print(resultado)
```

Aqui estou criando uma lista de tuplas, preservando o índice original da primeira lista:

```
tuplas = [(indice, valor) for indice, valor in enumerate(primeira_lista)]
```

Descomente o `print(tuplas)` para ver o resultado.

Depois ordeno pelo segundo valor:

```
tuplas.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Por fim, monto a segunda lista de novo, iterando sobre os índices das tuplas:

```
resultado = []
for indice, valor in tuplas:
    resultado.append(segunda_lista[indice])
```

A primeira lista pode ser ordenada usando simplesmente:

```
primeira_lista_ordenada = sorted(primeira_lista)
```

Comment: Dessa forma eu obtenho 
lista_ordenada = [[2, 3, 4, 6, 7], [3, 4, 4, 6, 8]].

O que quero é que cada elemento lista[0][i] esteja associado ao elemento lista[1][i], de tal forma que quando eu ordene lista[0] essa correspondência seja mantida.

Comment: Retificando: se você ordena lista[0], precisa ordenar lista[1] da mesma forma. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Só quero ordenar lista[0] em ordem crescente. O primeiro elemento da saída será lista_ordenada[0][0]=2, pois o menor elemento de lista[0] é lista[0][3]=2. Como lista[1][3]=4, o elemento lista_ordenada[1][0]=4 a saída deve ficar

lista_ordenada=[[2,......],[4,......]].

Não sei se está claro...